# Code shrinking on debug

Tags: android, proguard

Before I release the app, I am trying to test whether there will be any changes(methods, variables removed) if I code shrink with Instant run the app. I am following this [Enable code shrinking with Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#gradle-shrinker) but it does not show any signs in my code that was removed or changed.

```
android {
buildTypes {
         debug {
             minifyEnabled true
             useProguard false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                     'proguard-rules.pro'
         }  
   }     
}
```

Is there any way to check if there are changes made?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Shrinking options -printUsage and it will tell you dead code, which eventually will be removed during shrinking.

> -**printusage** [filename]
>   Specifies to list dead code of the input class files. The list is printed to the standard output or to the given file. For example, you can list the unused code of an application. Only applicable when shrinking.

Answer (score -1):

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some comments of what the code above is supposed to execute like